# How can you turn a JSON array into a single-column table in Snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have this JSON array:

```
["123","456"]
```

And I want to turn it into a table in Snowflake that looks like this:

```
| col1 |
| ---- |
| 123  |
| ---  |
| 456  |
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Can you share one sample json record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select f.value as col1
from lateral flatten(input => parse_json('[123,456]')) f;
```

gives:

```
VALUE
123
456
```

The [flatten](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/flatten.html) doc's are the one you want to read, to get access to lots of the object, and it has ways to handle nested objects and the likes.